# Can JavaScript code in browser be modified by hacker to gain access to unauthorized resource?

Tags: attacks, javascript

I have Spring Boot API app on the server side and VueJS app on the client side. Upon successful login, the server side sends JSON response that includes accountType with value either VIEW_GOLD or VIEW_SILVER, if accountType is VIEW_GOLD, the user is directed to view list of GoldBar object and so on like in this code in client side VueJS:

```
         if (response.data) {
             if (response.data.accountType === 'VIEW_GOLD') {

               $this.$router.replace({ name: 'GoldBars'})

             } 
             else if (response.data.accountType === 'VIEW_SILVER') {

               $this.$router.replace({ name: 'SilverBars'})
            }
```

The question is can a hacker view Goldbars when the  accountType is VIEW_SILVER by using hacker browser such as Tor ?

Comment: Not enough information to say - if the server side code that displays gold bars trusts the data supplied by the client to be correct, and doesn't verify it on each request, anyone can view gold bars, and they can do it from any vaguely modern browser with a built in developer toolbar (IE/Edge, Chrome/Opera, Firefox...)

Comment: Who is that "hacker"? Is it the user or an eavesdropper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every browser comes with powerful development tools. The usual hotkey to access them is <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Any user could use the JavaScript debugger of their browser to set a break-point in the line `if (response.data)`, wait until the break-point is reached, edit the value `response.data.accountType` to read `VIEW_GOLD` while the execution is paused and continue the execution of the javascript.

Some browsers like Chrome even allow to edit the JavaScript code of a website while it is loaded.

There is nothing you can really do to prevent users from using these tools.

So follow the dogma **never trust the client**! do not handle anything related to permission handling on the client-side. The server should know the permission level of the user and simply refuse to serve any information the user is not supposed to have access to.

**By the way:** This dogma does not just apply to web applications but any form of client-server architecture. The debugging tools for a binary client might not be as readily accessible as those in web browsers, but they do exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic authentication problem. You have your server-side code which is supposed to provide information as response to a request.

You want your server to provide the data of a "GoldView" (whatever this is) to authorized users only. This requires the server to receive some proof that the requesting entity is in fact authorized to get this data.

Handing out a token upon login (this can either be a simple session key, a JWT or something else) is a good idea **BUT** make sure nobody can forge a token on demand. In addition, this token **must** be sent to the server with each request, requiring authentication.

In general, assume the following:

- Whatever is contained in your VueJS app, can be read by an attacker (as you send it to them)
- **Everything** your server-side receives is malicious input until proven otherwise
- The server **has to check** each request and verify the requesting clients privileges, before sending out data
- Unless generating a token requires a server secret, an attack can forge arbitrary tokens

P.S.: Tor is not a "hacker browser" and cannot do anything magical to bypass your security measures. It's just a tricky proxy network which shouldn't concern you when it comes to server-side authentication (it's an entirely different topic).